# How to delete photo in Facebook

Tags: windows, facebook, synchronization

I'm writing a small windows application what is used to sync the photo between Facebook and user computer, I would like to delete the photo too when I delete it in my computer side, but Facebook don't provide the delete function in his API. How can I achieve it? I saw Apple iPhoto can do it, is Apple using private interface?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't delete photo via Facebook API?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6337969/cant-delete-photo-via-facebook-api)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook isn't a full-fledged photo management application.  It's a way to share information (including photos) between friends.  The API is very restrictive in order to protect privacy and data.

As far as I'm aware, there is no way you can delete any kind of Facebook user information through any public API or interface.

Comment: Thanks for your input, can I use the SDK to move the photo from A album to B album?

Comment: I don't think so.  I believe that what you can do with Facebook photos is limited to the methods found in the API:  http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API.  See the `photo.xxx` methods.